# HERE api, How to ignore traffic in all calculations

Tags: javascript, here-api

At my company, we calculate travel time for jobs based upon a website that gives the distance and time as if the driver was at the speed limit and there is no other traffic on the road. This is a mandatory requirement as the time of the day in which the calculation is done is rarely going to allow traffic patterns to align.

I am working to make the process faster by creating an internal website with a database containing all the relevant addresses. To do this I have written a web app using the HERE routing api in javascript; however, the travel time listed constantly changes despite my setting "'route_mode': 'shortest'" and "'traffic': 'disabled'".

Is there another setting that I have not found that would allow me to completely disregard traffic conditions in all my calculations?

If it helps, here is the function call:

```
async function get_distance_and_time(origin_coord,des_coord){
var dis;
var time;

var routingParameters = {
  'route_mode': 'fastest',
  'traffic': 'disabled',
  'transportMode': 'car',
  // The start point of the route:
  'origin': origin_coord,
  // The end point of the route:
  'destination': des_coord,
  // Include the route shape in the response
  'return': 'summary'
};

var onResult = await function(result) {
    if (result.routes.length) {
        dis = result.routes[0].sections[0].summary.length;
        time = result.routes[0].sections[0].summary.baseDuration;
        console.log(result.routes[0].sections[0].summary);
        
    }
    
}
var router = await platform.getRoutingService(null, 8);
await router.calculateRoute(routingParameters, onResult,
  function(error) {
    alert(error.message);
  });

var return_data = [dis,time];
return return_data;
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to calculate the route?

Comment: @RaymondCamden I added it. I didn't originally include it because it was just the generic call I saw in all the tutorials.

Comment: I believe that the earlier version of the routing service had this, not the most recent (it was a big update, so some older features aren't in yet). Can you try using v7 instead?

Answer (score 2):

BTW:

'route_mode': 'fastest',  'traffic': 'disabled' are incorrect.

Instead of 'route_mode' use please 'routingMode'

The parameter 'traffic' doesn't exist in the Routing API v8

---

Regarding with https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.9.1/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/departure-time.html you can read:

**Begin Route At Different Times**

The default departure time for a route is the time of the route request. In your request for a route, you can use the departureTime parameter to specify a different time.

A different departureTime will have various effects ranging from different traffic impact to road closures.

*If you specify departureTime as any, the route calculation will not take traffic flow and other time-dependent effects into account.* This can be useful when it is not certain that you're taking this route at a fixed time.

> departureTime=any

that allow you to completely disregard traffic conditions in all your calculations.

---

Please use our playgrounds:

http://demo.routing.ext.here.com/

http://refclient.ext.here.com/